# Уведомлен/уведомлён

Tags: ударение

Как правильно произнести?
Я увЕдомлю Вас
Я уведомлЮ Вас 
и по аналогии я уведомлЕн либо я уведомлЁн

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: "увЕдомлю". От слова "вЕдать". Согласитесь, "уведомлЮ" - можно язык сломать.))  "Уведомить" - глагол, совершенный вид, переходный, невозвратный, II спряжение, и тут тоже ударение ставится на Е: "УвЕдомить".

Comment: Во втором случае через Е ? уведомлен, а не уведомлён?

Comment: Может быть, увЕдомлю (млю вместо влю)?

Answer (score 1):

Уведомленный, -ен, -ена, -ено, -ены (не уведомлённый) Наверное, и в краткой форме так же